# Formula to Find Count of Odd Numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have 500 numbers (range A1:T25) and I have to find a formula to find the count of the odd numbers in that range. I do not see any way to use **`COUNTIF`** or **`ISODD`** or **`MOD`** (by 2). I am no expert in spreadsheet functions **at all**, so I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(ISODD(A1:T25); TRUE))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISODD(A1:T25)) @Tom Sharpe
```

Comment: =sumproduct(isodd(A1:D10)) also works which I didn't expect. Doesn't work in Excel.

Comment: How exactly does this work? If I remove the `ARRAYFORMULA(...)` part it doesn't work. What is this formula?

Comment: @whoreallycares2 arrayformula is needed because of range `ISODD(A1:T25)`