# Formula to Find Count of Even Numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, array-formulas

I have found this question/answer useful:

[Formula to Find Count of Odd Numbers in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318657/formula-to-find-count-of-odd-numbers-in-google-sheets)

but whilst it works for my array with odd numbers, I also want to count the even numbers and the equivalent with ISEVEN counts blank cells as even numbers giving an incorrect result there. How can I use the ISEVEN function whilst also telling the formula to ignore the blanks? I have tried the "<>" and ISNUMBER in almost every permutation and played around with COUNTIFS, but so far not got anything to work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> **Try these** formulas, Take a look at [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PNQWf27JluVkqC_bex4U2T3N9EJcNI5gw29-tqMQSyM/edit?usp=sharing)

**ODD**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(ISODD(FILTER(FLATTEN($A$1:$O$20),FLATTEN($A$1:$O$20)<>"")), TRUE))
```

**EVEN**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(ISEVEN(FILTER(FLATTEN($A$1:$O$20),FLATTEN($A$1:$O$20)<>"")), TRUE))
```

[**`COUNTA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en)

```
=COUNTA(A1:O20)
```

**Total check** *"EVEN output + ODD output"*

```
=B22+B23
```

**Blanks**

```
=(ROWS(A1:O20)*COLUMNS(A1:O20))-COUNTA($A$1:$O$20)
```

[image]